# To set up DHCP in OSX

Tags: dhcp, mac-osx, wifi, tcp

**How can you set up a DHCP for OSX such that you can access your Macbook's shared network by iPod Touch?**

I have enabled *internet sharing* in OSX settings
such that you I access the sharing by iPod.
However, I do not get the internet.

I have in Network settings > TCP/IP > Configure IPv4: *Using DHCP*.

I run the network with *Using DHCP with manual address* unsuccessfully. I used my real ip-address in the airport setting.

Comment: Superuser.com is probably a better forum for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open System Preferences

Click 'Sharing'

Click 'Internet Sharing'

Select the connection on your computer that you want to share (in my case the Ethernet)

Select the checkbox next to Internet Sharing to enable Internet sharing

Done